# Why my position is not being updated in my 2D array?

Tags: c

I am trying to update the player position in a 2D array that places a P marker. When I run put 4 for row and 4 for column number, it doesn't looks like it saved with my mark board function. Any help or hint appreciated. I am new to C programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function declaration here

//draw board function- it draws the board
char board[6][6] = {
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0','0','0'}
    };
void draw_board();

//mark board
char mark_board(int row_num, int column_num);

//main program
int main()
{
    //draw_board();
    int row_number;
    int column_number;

    printf("Which starting point you like to occupy?\n");

    printf("row number: ");
    int player_row = scanf("%d", &row_number);

    printf("column number: ");
    int player_column = scanf("%d", &column_number);

    mark_board(player_row,player_column);
    
    draw_board();
    return 0;
}

//function definition here
void draw_board()
{
    printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
    printf("   -----------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)// rows number
    {
        printf("%i| ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

char mark_board(int row_num, int column_num)
{
    int i,j;
    char mark = 'P';
    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)// rows number
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) //column number
        {
            board[row_num - 1][column_num - 1] = mark;
        }
    } 
    return board[i][j];
}
```

Here is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zECIA.png)

Comment: if output is text , better copy it here in question instead of an image

Comment: `int player_column = scanf("%d", &column_number);` `scanf` returns number of items read not the item itself, you have to call `mark_board(row_number, column_number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main()` function, you assign the result of `scanf()` to **player_row** and **player_column**, considering the input was correct, it was always 1, since you got *1* integer from the keyboard. This should work:

```
int main(void)
{
    //draw_board();
    int row_number;
    int column_number;

    printf("Which starting point you like to occupy?\n");

    printf("row number: ");
     if (scanf("%d", &row_number)!=1)
     {
         return -1;
     }

    printf("column number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &column_number)!=1) //Checking the return value of scanf
    {
        return -1;
    }

    mark_board(row_number,column_number);
    
    draw_board();
    return 0;
}
```

You should also consider validating the range of your input, you don't want an index that is out of bounds of your array, that is **UB**